# How can I change the angle of a vector by having another angle in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, math, vector

I'm making a game in Swift, and I have a vector that is normalized and then I apply a random scalar. This vector has -of course- an angle that I calculate doing:

```
atan2(vec.dx, vec.dy)
```

The angle values I'm receiving in the console when I push the object through different directions is the following.

Left = -1.5
Up = 0,0
Right = 1,5

Here's a picture showing what I mean.

[image]

Now, what I would like to accomplish is, if the object is pushed lower than -0.5 or lower than 0.5 (i.e: -1.5 or 1.5) the minimum angle would be the -0.5 and 0.5. I would like to modify the vector that way so those angle values are the minimum.

So how can I achieve this? Sorry, I suck at math. And thanks in advance.

After digging more, i found a "way" to do it in Java and I kinda translated it into Swift. What i have is this:

```
/* Calculate the angle of `vector` */
func angle() -> CGFloat {
    return atan2(dx, dy)
}

func rotate(vec: CGVector, degrees: Double) -> CGVector {
    let degToRad = M_PI/180
    return vec.rotateRadians(vec, radians: degrees * degToRad)
}

func rotateRadians(vec: CGVector, radians: Double) -> CGVector {
    let ca = CGFloat(cos(radians))
    let sa = CGFloat(sin(radians))
    return CGVector(dx: ca * vec.dx - sa * vec.dy, dy: sa * vec.dx + ca * vec.dy)
}
```

And then i use it like this:

```
let oldVec = CGVector(dx: pB.x - pA.x, dy: pB.y - pA.y) // Vector from A to B

        let random = CGFloat(randomNumber(280...330))
        let scalar = random / oldVec.length()

        var radian = 0.0
        if oldVec.angle() <= -0.5 {
            radian = -0.5
        }else if oldVec.angle() >= 0.5 {
            radian = 0.5
        }

        var newVec = oldVec.rotateRadians(oldVec, radians: radian)
```

Is this fine? It seems to kind of work. But i'm not sure if I'm doing something totally wrong.

Comment: It sounds like checking the math could be a valuable investment. `(cos(x), sin(x))` are the coordinates of a vector of length 1 pointing to angle `x`.

Comment: But what do i do with that? if i say vec( cos(dx), sin(dy) ) = -1.5 ) is that right?

Comment: Your 1.5 value on this figure matches angle 0 and your -1.5 matches angle π. You will have to scale it to that.

Comment: Give me a few minutes, i'm trying to read more about this so i can understand what you gave me :( coz im so stucked haha.

Comment: "modify the vector that way so those angle values are the minimum" And you want to keep vector length equal, right?

Comment: Yes, vector length equal, idc if it's normalized, i just need the angle to be changed to a minimum if exceeds the limits of -0.5 or 0.5, i believe those are expressed in radians, right?

Comment: i think i was able to manage it, and it's kinda "working" but dunno, i will add the code i found in another stackoverflow post but it was in another section. Let me know what you think.

Comment: A full circle is 2π radians. An arc of 90° would be 1/4 of that, so π/2 radians.

Comment: So the code i posted up there is wrong?

Comment: What do these values `-1.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.5, 1.5' mean?

Comment: @MBo those values are displayed in console when i push the ball to left, up and right.